# cd into the external sd-card directory using adb shell

Tags: external-sd, shell

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (actually, many of them) and I need to regularly push some files inside the **external physically removable** SD card of my tablets.

Android handles internal and external storage as follows:

```
/storage
  ├ emulated/0/ /* this is the internal storage partition */
  └ 9102-ABF4 /* this is the external removable SD card partition */
```

I thought I could find this path by browsing to the folder which is not named `/emulated` inside `/storage` since the other one is the one I want.

I want, using device's shell through adb, to navigate to (using command cd) a directory that I don't know the path of (`9102-ABF4` written above, located inside `/storage/`)

Comment: what is your question? `cd /storage/????-????`?

Comment: @alecxs I want, using device's shell through adb, go (using command `cd`) inside a directory that I don't know (`9102-ABF4` written above, located inside `/storage`)

Comment: @puffo The command alecxs presented to you does exactly what you want to do: cd into a directory the name you don't know (but you know the pattern of the directory name). Just try it out.

Comment: @alecxs You should make an answer from your comment. Using wildcards with cd is a nice trick especially as it should work perfectly for all sd-cards as the pattern is always the same.

Comment: @Robert i am afraid the question is off-topic so i won't answer - besides this it's not worth it because that are basics in shell coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your Android is 6 or above, and if your are connected through USB cable and your Android have USB debugging enabled, and if you have installed:

```
sudo apt install adb perl
```

put in a Linux terminal:

```
adb shell sm list-volumes public | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]')
```

This will show the micro SD card identification, example:

9102-ABF4

I made several scripts to automate send and receive files from Linux to Android and from Android to Linux:

https://github.com/wachin/adb-send-files

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe adb shell supports tab completion.  It makes reference to a directory in a command, but if you don't know the path you will need to use `adb shell ls` command to list the directory before using the path in an adb push command.  For example, `adb shell ls storage/9102-ABF4` will let you explore the external SD card that is on your device.

In terms of changing the working directory on your terminal, I don't believe you can do this because adb does not support interactive mode like nslookup.  You are using a shell (adb shell) within a shell (bash, PowerShell, cmd, etc).